# camera startPreview failed

Tags: android, camera

I am creating a camera app but I have problems on `startPreview`, it sends me:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
```

here is my camera *Activity*:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview  mPreview;
private Target_Frame targetFrame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);




    mCamera=getCameraInstance();
    mPreview=new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);




    FrameLayout preview=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

}




/** Check if this device has a camera only if not specified in the manifest */
public boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

/**Check if the device has flash*/
public boolean checkFlash(Context context){
    if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        //the device has flash
        return true;
    }else{
        //no flash
        return false;
    }

}




@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseCamera();
}




@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    //Test if i have to put all this code like in onCreate
    if(mCamera!=null){
        return;
    }
    mCamera=getCameraInstance();

    if(mPreview!=null){
        return;
    }
    mPreview=new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);


}


private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}}
```

And here is my *SurfaceView* code:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        Parameters parameters= mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my error log:

```
12-01 13:17:01.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-01 13:17:01.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview

12-01 13:17:01.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.example.prueba.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:36)
```

Comment: Sorry, I find your variable names terribly confusing. `mholder/holder/camera/mcamera/preview/mpreview` when you use `mholder` instead of `holder` in surfaceChanged, and when `preview` and `mPreview` are instances of different classes. I had to give up, I was going crosseyed! I can't say that there is no mistake, but I do think you'd find it easier if you used names more consistently and perhaps with more description in them. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi the variable names are the same of the android sdk examples,but maybe i will hace to change them as you say. Don´t you see any error? i have check a lot of things but i don´t know what to do now

Comment: I've never programmed a `SurfaceView` into a `FrameLayout`. It may be entirely correct, but I'd start with something simpler. Like adding the `SurfaceView` directly to to `camera_layout` in the xml file, and once you have that working, change the layout to the way you have here. I have no idea if that will fix the problem but it will make the debugging simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved deleting some lines in surfaceChanged

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        Log.d("Function", "surfaceChanged iniciado");
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here


        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So the error must be in i one of these lines:

```
Parameters parameters= mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Someone could explain me what was wrong in those lines?

Comment: I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Is (w, h) a valid preview size for your camera?

You can use `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()` to get all of the valid preview sizes.

Comment: This is most likely the reason of the `RuntimeException`. For some devices, call to [Camera.setParameters()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setParameters(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters)) with unsupported preview size can cause `RuntimeException`. For others, the exception is thrown on [Camera.startPreview()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startPreview())

Answer (score 4):

Its late, but if someones looking for the answer

The variables w and h are not the optimal preview sizes . You can get optimal preview sizes using the function

```
public static Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
```

and you can call the function using

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
..
size=getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), w, h);
 parameters.setPreviewSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
..

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera preview started.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and it's because I didn't call releaseCamera on the onPause the first time I start my app.
After a reboot, everything works fine ^^