# App crash after obfuscation on red5Pro library

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-proguard, red5pro

Without obfuscation using Proguard, everything is working fine.

When I enable Proguard, app gets crash on this line-

```
mStream.publish(liveStream.streamName, RECORD_TYPE);
```

where mStream is the instance of com.red5pro.streaming.R5Stream.
I'm using **red5Pro** library for broadcasting and not getting any stack trace. I have created an issue on Github also on this repo-
https://github.com/red5pro/streaming-android/issues/119

but didn't get any response yet.

I have tried solutions from other questions but still getting this error.
What should I do in my proguard configuration to resolve this problem?

I have already added following lines in my proguard rules-

```
-keep class com.red5pro.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.red5pro.**
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660009/camera-startpreview-failed

Comment: @AkshayNandwana - As I already mentioned, I have tried other answers. and main thing is I'm getting problem only after enabling proguard.